# Independently animating transform properties with web animations api

Tags: animation, web-animations

Is it possible to animate the different parts of the transform property independently in one animation?

for example:

```
const lineAnimation = [
  { transform: 'scaleX(0)', offset: 0 },
  { transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: 0 },

  { transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: .25 },
  { transform: 'scaleX(1)', offset: .5 },

  { transform: 'translateX(100%)', offset: 1 },
]

// Timing object also defined...

loadLine1.animate(
  lineAnimation,
  loadLine1Timing
);
```

I would like to animate scaling and translation in the same animation for the same element but at different timings.

This particular example isn't working and seems to only be affecting the translateX and not the scale.

How could I modify this to transform both at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible. You need to create an extra wrapper around your `loadLine1` element (e.g. if it is an SVG element, a `<g>` element, or if it is HTML, a `<div>` or `<span>` element), then you need to animate `scale` on `loadLine1` and `translate` on the wrapper, or vice-versa depending on the desired effect.

Alternatively, you could write something like:

```
const lineAnimation = [
  { transform: 'scaleX(0) translateX(0%)', offset: 0 },
  { transform: 'scaleX(0.5) translateX(0%)', offset: .25 },
  { transform: 'scaleX(1) translateX(33%)', offset: .5 },
  { transform: 'scaleX(1) translateX(100%)', offset: 1 },
]

loadLine1.animate(
  lineAnimation,
  loadLine1Timing
);
```

(You might want to reverse the order of the `scaleX()` and `translateX()` components depending on the desired effect.)

In future this will be possible via two further means.

Firstly, [CSS Transforms Level 2](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/) specifies [individual properties for `translate` and `scale`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms). This is implemented in Chrome but only behind a flag. I expect it will be implemented in Firefox in the near future.

This would allow you to write your animation as:

```
const lineAnimation = [
  { scale: 0, offset: 0 },
  { translate: '0%', offset: 0 },

  { translate: '0%', offset: .25 },
  { scale: 1, offset: .5 },

  { translate: '100%', offset: 1 },
]

loadLine1.animate(
  lineAnimation,
  loadLine1Timing
);
```

Secondly, Web Animations defines additive animation which would allow you to achieve this as follows:

```
const scaleAnimation = [
  { transform: 'scaleX(0)', offset: 0 },
  { transform: 'scaleX(1)', offset: .5 },
];

const translateAnimation = [
  { transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: 0 },
  { transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: .25 },
  { transform: 'translateX(100%)', offset: 1 },
];

loadLine1.animate(
  scaleAnimation,
  loadLine1Timing
);
loadLine1.animate(
  translateAnimation,
  { ...loadLine1Timing, composite: 'add' }
);
```

This is implemented in Firefox but only enabled in Nightly builds. It is also implemented in Chrome, I believe, but only enabled behind the experimental web platform features flag. I hope this will ship in both browsers and the polyfill in early 2018.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be keeping an eye out for when this is all implemented.